# run highcharter in jupyterlab / jupyternotebooks

Tags: html, r-highcharter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to render some `highcharter` charts in jupyterlab

```
data(diamonds, economics_long, mpg, package = "ggplot2")
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class))
```

to get `plotlywrapper` working you need to install an extension. I can imagine something similar has to be built for `highcharter`?

error message:

```
HTML widgets cannot be represented in plain text (need html)
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://blog.ouseful.info/2018/04/26/r-htmlwidgets-in-jupyter-notebooks/

```
data(diamonds, economics_long, mpg, package = "ggplot2")
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter)
x=hchart(mpg, "scatter", hcaes(x = displ, y = hwy, group = class)) %>%
hc_size(width=800, height = 400)
saveWidget(x, 'demox.html', selfcontained = FALSE)
display_html('<iframe src="demox.html", width = 900, height = 500 ></iframe>')
```